# Problem uploading converted image file(.dng) into dropbox

Tags: node.js, directory, upload, compression, dropbox

I have an application in node js in which I am uploading the image to the node server after that  I compress the file to reduce the size. After that, I upload it to dropbox but the uploaded file has a 0-byte size. I don't understand the problem. Below is the code that I used.

```
var dir ="C:\\Users\\uploads\\converted\\"+foldername;
fs.readdir("C:\\Users\\uploads\\converted\\"+foldername, function (err, files) {
    //handling error
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 
    else {
        //listing all files using forEach
         files.forEach(function (file) {
             console.log(file); 
             var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: 'xxxx' });
             dbx.filesUpload({path: '/'+link+'/'+file , contents: file.data})
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
         });
      }
});
```

-------------Update after trying code---------------------

Thank you for your solution. I tried this code with changes but this time even the image file is not uploaded to dropbox. Please find my updated code below.

```
var namefile= path.basename("C:\\Users\\uploads\\converted\\"+foldername+"\\"+req.file.originalname,".ARW" );

var image =namefile+".dng";
fs.readFile("C:\\Users\\uploads\\converted\\"+foldername+"\\"+image, function(err, data) {
    
    var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: 'XXXX' });
    dbx.filesUpload({path: '/'+link+'/'+image, contents: data})
        .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
});
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Problem-uploading-converted-image-file-dng-into-dropbox/td-p/473911 ]